# Java JAXB : Namespace attribute in subelement causes element not to appear after marshalling

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, attributes, marshalling

I import some xml via REST. The XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<QueryResult>
<ResultXml>
<rowset xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset">
<Row>
<Column0>0</Column0>
</Row>
</rowset>
</ResultXml>
</QueryResult>
```

When I harvest the xml and then marshal it the ResultXml element is empty.
When I **remove** the xmlns attribute from the original xml the ResultXml elment is populated.

Is anyone able to advise how I can amend the Rowset class created by JAXB to marshal the objects successfully whilst retaining the xmlns attribute?

The top of the JAXB class with the xmlns is:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
"row"
})
public static class Rowset {
@XmlElement(name = "Row", required = true)
protected QueryResult.ResultXml.Rowset.Row row;
@XmlAttribute(name = "xmlns")
protected String xmlns;
```

Comment: Specify the `namespace` attribute on the `@XmlElement` annotation for the `rowset` field of the `ResultXml` class, e.g. `@XmlElement(name = "rowset", namespace = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset")`

Comment: Andreas's advice resolved the issue.